# Multiple GPUComputationRenderer instances

Tags: three.js, gpgpu

I have multiple GPUComputationRenderer instances. I don't use them at the same time. I update one, then update a different one. For some reason it seems like they affect each other. I don't have a simple working example, it's part of a complicated project I'm working on. I notice it when I set the two different GPUComputationRenderer instances to have different sizes. Are they somehow sharing some resource in the background?

Comment: Impossible to figure out your problem without seeing some *minimal* code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to reproduce the issue without sharing thousands of lines of code.